# RequireJS plugin: load timeouts experienced when using plugin

Tags: javascript, requirejs

Using RequireJS I'm building an app which make extensive use of widgets. For each widget I have at least 3 separate files:

- request.js containing code for setting up request/response handlers to request a widget in another part of my application
- controller.js containing handling between model and view
- view.js containing handling between user and controller

Module definition in request.js:

```
define(['common/view/widget/entity/term/list/table/controller'],
function(WidgetController) { ... });
```

Module definition in controller.js:

```
define(['common/view/widget/entity/term/list/table/view'],
function(WidgetView) { ... });
```

Module definition of view.js is:

```
define(['module','require'],function(module,require) {

'use strict';

var WidgetView = <constructor definition>;

    return WidgetView;
});
```

I have lots of these little situations as above in the case of widgets I have developed. What I dislike is using the full path every time when a module is requiring another module and both are located in the same folder. I'd like to simply specify as follows (assuming we have a RequireJS plugin which solves this for us):

```
define(['currentfolder!controller'],
function(WidgetController) { ... });
```

For this, I have written a small plugin, as I couldn't find it on the web:

```
define({
    load: function (name, parentRequire, onload, config) {

        var path = parentRequire.toUrl('.').substring(config.baseUrl.length) + '/' + name;

        parentRequire([path], function (value) {
            onload(value);
        });
    }
});
```

As you might notice, in its basic form it looks like the example of the RequireJS plugins documentation.

Now in some cases, the above works fine (e.g. from the request.js to the controller.js), but in other cases a load timeout occurs (from controller.js to view.js). When I look at the paths which are generated, all are proper RequireJS paths. Looking at the load timeouts, the following is logged:

```
Timestamp: 13-09-13 17:27:10
Error: Error: Load timeout for modules: currentfolder!view_unnormalized2,currentfolder!view
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#timeout
Source File: http://localhost/app/vendor/requirejs/require.js?msv15z
Line: 159
```

The above log was from a test I did with only loading the view.js from controller.js using currentfolder!view in the list of modules in the define statement. Since I only requested currentfolder!view once, I'm confused as to why I both see currentfolder!view_unnormalized2 and currentfolder!view in the message.

Any idea as to why this might be happening?

Comment: BTW `_unnormalized<id>` are expected logs when a module returns a 404 because of the way Require.js handle loading internally. Check in the _network_ pane to see how the request ended (404 or anything)

Comment: There is no 404 as there is no request made at all, but your other answer was sufficient for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer may not answer your primary questions, but it will help you achieve what you're trying to do with your plugin.

In fact, Require.js support relative paths for requiring modules when using CommonJS style. Like so:

```
define(function( require, exports, module ) {
  var relativeModule = require("./subfolder/module");

  module.exports = function() {
    console.log( relativeModule );
  };
});
```

Comment: Great. I had experimented with this, but I couldn't get it to work properly. I'm new to RequireJS so I guess it was a case of proper RTFM. This works for me!